# Why isn't it called "The Hateful Nine"?

Tags: plot-explanation, title, the-hateful-eight

I gather that John Ruth's driver O.B. is not considered one of the "hateful eight," but he is present for all of the film's events and seems as much a part of the story as any of the others.

I like the rhyming title, but I was confused during the film about who the eight were when there were clearly nine people present at Minnie's, at least until folks start dying and

> another character comes out of his hiding place.

Comment: it might be related to the eight character's professions.

Comment: I don't think he hated anyone.

Comment: It doesn't rhyme.  :)

Comment: I haven't seen the film yet but it sounds like a meta-joke, since The Hateful Eight isn't really Tarantino's 8th movie.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I agree, but you can just about keep it to his eighth movie if you only count movies he both wrote and directed and you count _Kill Bill_ as one movie. It's a stretch.

Comment: I lack points to answer this question (please upvote me), but this promotional video numbers and names the exact eight characters. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKOfJvbmD0g

Answer (score 9):

General Sandy Smithers, you may recall, was just some chump sitting around a fire and wasn't really hateful towards any in the group.  he had no beef with anyone, he was just in the right place at the right time.  Also, Ruth's driver (O.B. Jackson) wasn't hateful towards anyone either.  Which leaves:

- Major Marquis Warren - Samuel L. Jackson
- John Ruth - Kurt Russell
- Daisy Domergue - Jennifer Jason Leigh
- Sheriff Chris Mannix - Walton Goggins
- Bob - Demián Bichir
- Oswaldo Mobray - Tim Roth
- Joe Gage - Michael Madsen
- Jody - Channing Tatum

8 main players.  Also, don't over look the fact that this is Tarantino's 8th movie, the movie's overture contains exactly 8 notes used repetitiously, while in the background there are 8 distinctive mountain peaks.  See any "theme" there that might lend to the movie being called "The Hateful Eight"?

Comment: Actually I was under the impression that Channing's character was one of the 8 and O.B. was considered a by-stander like Bruce Dern's character.

Comment: It's possible.  Probable, even, given that he really doesn't have a "dog in the fight" either, much like Smithers.  In that case, Jody (Tatum's character) would be considered the 8th, with Smithers and Jackson being [MacGuffins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin)..

Comment: Yea, I'd remove OB from this list and add Channing's character to make the *hateful* 8. There were plenty more characters, but they weren't hateful.

Comment: In the "cast" section, the Wikipedia article on the movie gives nicknames to eight of the character--those who are present for during the film's main action, except for O.B. and Jody (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hateful_Eight#Cast).  It's not clear where those nicknames come from, but I assume it's from press materials and the like.  They're clearly propped up as the movie's main characters, which is is why I assume that O.B. and Jody are not part of the "eight."

Comment: I'd think Jody is more hateful than Smithers.  If anything, I'd take O.B. off my list above and replace him with Jody, as DA suggested.

Comment: @CarlFink the grouping and nicknames of the principal eight characters are given in the souvenir program handed out as part of the 70mm roadshow presentations, as seen here: http://imgur.com/a/oxM2M

Comment: General Smithers didn't hate anyone? I don't think so. He actually *dies* because of his hate. Even if we accept that it was another man's hate that in turn intentionally provoked his, he still dies because of his hate. And even before that incident he hated Warren.

Comment: Gerneral Sandy Smithers is absolutely one of the eight and full of hate. Against "niggers" and against the murderer of his sun, standing in front of him as black one.

Comment: I agree with @NapoleonWilson, Smithers is the 8th guy in that list not Judy, because Smithers had some hatred but Judy didn't particularly hate anyone, he was there only on a mission to rescue his sister.

Comment: @CarlFink The "nicknames" are also shown on the character posters: http://movieweb.com/hateful-eight-character-posters-tarantino/

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKOfJvbmD0g) promotional featurette from the Weinstein Company (on the FILMISNOW YouTube) numbers and names the “eight” thus:

[image: promo still 1]
1: “The Bounty Hunter” Major Marquis Warren (Samuel L Jackson)

[image: promo still 2]
2: “The Hangman” John Ruth (Kurt Russell)

[image: promo still 3]
3: “The Confederate” General Sandy Smithers (Bruce Dern)

[image: promo still 4]
4: “The Sheriff” Chris Mannix (Walton Goggins)

[image: promo still 5]
5: “The Mexican” Bob (Demián Bichir)

[image: promo still 6]
6: “The Little Man” Oswaldo Mobray (Tim Roth)

[image: promo still 7]
7: “The Cow Puncher” Joe Gage (Michael Madsen)

[image: promo still 8]
8: “The Prisoner” Daisy Domergue (Jennifer Jason Leigh)

Answer (score 0):

OB and sheriff Chris Mannix were not among the hateful eight because Mannix gave up his hate in the end, and apparently found somekind of redemption through accepting major Warren and the Lincoln letter. While Jody, Daisy, grouch, Bob, Pete were unredeemable killers and gang members, Smithers wrought consequences because of his hate, and John Ruth and major warren were unrepentant, retaining their hate to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the 5 in the outlaw gang and the 3 dead outlaws that Sam Jackson's character was bringing in to town, Making 8. That to me sounds like something Tarantino would do for one last question that everyone would talk about, as well as a last laugh. Everyone else wasn't down right hateful. They had jobs to do and they did them.